# Check if a value is in a file: best and fastest practice?

Tags: perl

I need to check if a particular value--a string with no whitespace--is in a file, at a specific position. The file contains various lines of data and each line comprises data separated by * and a whitespace. The value we look for is always the sixth value of each line. Ex. (otherval1* otherval2* otherval3* otherval4* otherval5* *value-to-get** etc.)  but that same value could be found at another position in a line. But we don't want to get that value. The file can be open by other users during this check, so it needs to be flock. What would be the best and fastest way to do it. I can think of two ways:

```
my $value = "qt7nxve";
my $completed = 0; #if the value is found in the file at the sixth position of a line, $completed will take the value of 1.
```

**First way: gathering data in an array**

```
open(INFO, "$outfile1") or die ("Couldn't open datafile");
flock(INFO, 2);
my @datadone = <INFO>;
close(INFO);

foreach my $line (@datadone) {
my @liner = split(/\* /, $line);
if ($liner[5] eq $value) { $completed = 1;}
}
```

**Second way: using while and an array**

```
open(INFO, "$outfile1") or &dienice("Couldn't open datafile");
flock(INFO, 2);
while (<INFO>) {
my @datadone = <INFO>;
foreach my $line (@datadone) {
    my @liner = split(/\* /, $line);
    if ($liner[5] eq $value) { $completed = 1; }
        }
    }
close(INFO);
```

The following code appears faster, but it can't be used, since it could find the value at another position than the sixth position in a line and $completed would incorrectly take the value of 1.

```
open(INFO, "$outfile1") or die ("Couldn't open datafile");
flock(INFO, 2);
while (<INFO>) {
    if ( $_ =~ m/$value/) {
    $completed = 1;
            }
    }
close(INFO);
```

So what is the best and fastest practice (including any other way)?

Comment: Are there any other columns after the sixth? In the vain hope that it's the last column, I might suggest using an end anchor in a single regexp. Also the `while` *will* be faster since it's reading the buffer and not stepping through an array of a file totally loaded into memory. You might still see some gains putting the split in that loop.

Comment: the sixth value is not the last column, there are many other values coming afterward.

Comment: If you are on *nix you could use grep to check if the value is in the file at all before you decide to open it.

Comment: Which OS will this script be running on?

Comment: You have to remove the while loop in the second solution.

Comment: Have you done any benchmark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest I can possibly think is to make the regex do your column-counting for you:

```
qr/ (?:           # open non-capturing group
        .*?       # anything up until...
        \* [ ]    # a star and a space
     ){5}         # five of these groups
     value-to-get # the literal value you are looking for
     \* [ ]       # closed by a star and a space
  /x; # <- allows eXpanded notation
```

Because you specify `'* '` as the column delimiter, the column has to stop at `'* '` Making the cautious match (`.*?`) before this, means that it matches everything up to the delimiter. Thus you want to find 5 of these groupings and then the value you are looking for followed by the `'* '`.

And if this matches, I would put the line like this:

```
last if $completed = m/(?:.*?\*[ ]){5}value-to-get\*[ ]/;
```

This approach assumes that there is not some elaborate escaping or quoting protocol that would allow a literal `'* '` in the column.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using `last` to leave whatever loop construct you are using once a match is found:

```
my $completed = 0;
while (<INFO>) {
    my @data = split /\* /, $_;

    if ($data[5] eq $value) {
        $completed = 1;
        last;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider,`my @data = split /\* /, $_, 7;` as including the LIMIT parameter can significantly increase performance, since the OP said *"the sixth value is not the last column, there are many other values coming afterward."* in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for the best and fastest way, but you haven't specified what "best" means; nor have you given any reason to believe that you're not trying to perform premature optimization. Keeping those points in mind, here is *a* solution.

When dealing with delimited data, I like to use [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.32/lib/Text/CSV.pm). You can use any single-byte character as a delimiter. If you also have [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Text-CSV_XS-1.04/CSV_XS.pm) installed, you will get a performance boost. The following will print `found` if the specified value is found in the sixth column anywhere in the file. Parsing stops as soon as a match is found.

Note that this will not work if any of your fields can contain `*` characters (unless there is some sort of quoting mechanism like in the CSV spec).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
    sep_char => '*',
    allow_whitespace => 1,
    binary => 1,
    auto_diag => 1
}) or die "Cannot use CSV: " . Text::CSV->error_diag();

open my $fh, '<', 'infile' or die $!;

my $found;
my $value = 'qt7nxve';

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
    if ($row->[5] eq $value) {
        $found = 1;
        last;
    }
}

close $fh;

say 'found' if $found;
```

Comment: `sep_char => '* '` Also, the file needs to be locked--somehow.  `flock`'s good *only if* other apps accessing the file are also using it.

Comment: @Kenosis The `allow_whitespace` option handles the space(s) between fields. `sep_char` can only be a single-byte character.

Comment: @Kenosis As for your point about locking, you are of course correct, I have yet to address it.